# [[deprecated]] incompatible with using but compatible with typedef

Tags: g++, c++14, typedef, deprecation-warning, using-declaration

I discovered (with g++ 6.3) that I can use the `[[deprecated]]` attribute to deprecate a typedef (`[[deprecated]] typedef longname shortname;`) but not a `using` declaration (`[[deprecated]] shortname = longname;`).

So I was wondering, is this intended (if yes, why?)? Or is this a bug?

This as a MWE:

```
#include <vector>

namespace our { 
  using vector = std::vector<float>;
} 

//[[deprecated("use the namespace 'our'")]] using myvector = std::vector<float>;
[[deprecated("use the namespace 'our'")]] typedef std::vector<float> myvector;

int main() { 
  myvector a;
  return a.size();
}
```

gives depending on which of the lines is commented in the following warning (intended):

```
g++  -march=native -std=c++11 -m64 -O2 -g -Wextra -Wall -Wshadow -lstdc++ -m64 -g -march=native -flto  main.cpp   -o main
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:11:12: warning: ‘myvector’ is deprecated: use the namespace 'our' [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   myvector a;
            ^
main.cpp:8:70: note: declared here
 [[deprecated("use the namespace 'our'")]] typedef std::vector<float> myvector;
                                                                      ^~~~~~~~
```

or the following error (unintended)

```
g++  -march=native -std=c++11 -m64 -O2 -g -Wextra -Wall -Wshadow -lstdc++ -m64 -g -march=native -flto  main.cpp   -o main
main.cpp:7:43: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
 [[deprecated("use the namespace 'our'")]] using myvector = std::vector<float>;
                                           ^~~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:11:3: error: ‘myvector’ was not declared in this scope
   myvector a;
   ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:12:10: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
   return a.size();
          ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[[deprecated]]` statement can not be placed at that position in the using statement (though I think in the line before would be nice).

Out of these

```
//using [[deprecated("use the namespace 'our'")]] myvector = std::vector<float>;
using myvector [[deprecated("use the namespace 'our'")]] = std::vector<float>;
//using myvector = [[deprecated("use the namespace 'our'")]] std::vector<float>;
//[[deprecated("use the namespace 'our'")]] typedef std::vector<float> myvector;
```

The first won't compile, clang gives a nicer error message in this case

```
clang++ -Weverything -std=c++14 -O2 -g main.cpp   -o main
main.cpp:4:18: warning: alias declarations are incompatible with C++98 [-Wc++98-compat]
  using vector = std::vector<float>;
                 ^
main.cpp:7:11: warning: C++11 attribute syntax is incompatible with C++98 [-Wc++98-compat]
    using [[deprecated("use the namespace 'our'")]] myvector = std::vector<float>;
          ^
main.cpp:7:11: error: an attribute list cannot appear here
    using [[deprecated("use the namespace 'our'")]] myvector = std::vector<float>;
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                             [[deprecated("use the namespace 'our'")]]
main.cpp:7:64: warning: alias declarations are incompatible with C++98 [-Wc++98-compat]
    using [[deprecated("use the namespace 'our'")]] myvector = std::vector<float>;
                                                               ^
main.cpp:13:3: warning: 'myvector' is deprecated: use the namespace 'our' [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  myvector a;
  ^
main.cpp:7:53: note: 'myvector' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    using [[deprecated("use the namespace 'our'")]] myvector = std::vector<float>;
                                                    ^
main.cpp:14:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') to
      'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  return a.size();
  ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~
5 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

So this points out that the attribute is "just in the wrong place" (and interestingly the deprecation warning gets later still printed as desired!)

The third prints a warning for gcc (though not what we want) `warning: ignoring attributes applied to class type ‘std::vector<float>’ outside of definition [-Wattributes]` or and error for clang `'deprecated' attribute cannot be applied to types`.

The second is what we want.